# Error Upgrading from Magento 2.3.4 to Magento 2.4.1

Tags: magento2, composer, magento2.3.4, magento-upgrade, magento2.4

I tried to upgrade from Magento 2.3.4 to Magento 2.4.1 using these commands:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.0 --no-update
composer update
```

then i got the following error like this:

[image]

Comment: first you try disable two-factor -auth and run again your command.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you've already installed all the required extensions with php7.4 and elastic search prior to upgrading, just download the magento2.4 package, put it in your magento2 core folder, and run this command `php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://localhost/magento2 --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento2 --db-user=root --db-password=admin123 --backend-frontname=admin --admin-firstname=admin --admin-lastname=admin --admin-email=admin@something.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=UTC --use-rewrites=1"`. I've upgraded to 2.4.0 yesterday and it's working fine. If you find any issue, you can ask.

Answer (score 0):

Please install Spomky-labs using composer command as per your version requirement.

**composer require spomky-labs/otphp**